# Pause/Stop Microsoft streams embed video in html page on model close

Tags: javascript, iframe, modal-dialog, azure-media-player

I have Microsoft stream video iframe embed on html page pop-up modal. The video is displayed on Modal pop-up when a button is clicked and plays with default controls. When i close the modal pop, the video still runs on the background. I need to stop/pause the video when the modal pop-up is closed. I have tried with JavaScript video pause scripts but nothing works out. Streams runs with Azure player, Any suggestion to control the video with JavaScript

Comment: I was able to stop the video by resetting the iframe.